# How to control which text Narrator reads

Tags: winapi, narrator

I need to add some text to what Narrator reads from a Win32 ListView. E.g., besides a listview item's caption, it needs to say the type of the item (the type is defined by the application in this case). Is there any special message or another kind of request performed by Narrator for obtaining texts, or is it limited to regular WM_GETTEXT and similar messages?

The question is about Win32 or COM API including shell (i.e., not .NET / WinForms / WPF).

Comment: Narrator presumably uses [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) to discover the text to read.

Comment: @IInspectable yes, than kyou. Unfortunately, that technology is very different from Win32, and it is not clear even where to start :). I hoped for some specific hints, maybe.

Comment: UI Automation is exposed through [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/the-component-object-model). I suppose the [provider programmer's guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-providerportal) is what you need, although I don't have any experience implementing provider interfaces. MFC's [`CWnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class) implementation could be a place to look for a (reference) implementation.